# R: For loop- For each subset, add character values that incorporate the subsetted factor level and unique iD numbers

Tags: r

Apologies for the terrible title. However, I had trouble making this particular question a concise title.

I have a data frame like so (Note: it is over 50000 rows long with over 30 Lepidoptera families):

```
df<- 
       lepfam        lep_notes                lep_species

       Geometridae                               Eois sp
       Erebidae     black/orange           
       Erebidae     black spikes           
       Erebidae     redthorax/red legs     
       Noctuidae    fuzzy/ green          
       Noctuidae    black hair/greenbody    
       Noctuidae    fuzzy/green             
       Saturnidae                                Polyphemous sp
```

I would like to loop through the current dataframe `df` and fill in blank `lep_species` values with morpho species names conditional on the `lep_notes`. The `lep_species` name needs to include the `lepfam` name and a consecutive number denoting a different morpho species (e.g. `Erebidae morphosp1`). If it is easier it can also be `Erebidae 1`, but I would prefer the "morphosp" as part of the name. Therefore, I need to subset the data by each unique `lepfam`. Then, I want to give a `lep_species` name to those that currently have no name but have a descriptor in `lep_notes`. For each unique descriptor in `lep_notes` , the loop would designate a unique name to individuals sharing that descriptor. The data frame would look like this:

```
 df<- 
       lepfam     lep_notes                lep_species

       Geometridae                       Eois sp           
       Erebidae   black/orange           Erebidae_morphosp1
       Erebidae   black spikes           Erebidae_morphosp2
       Erebidae   redthorax/red legs     Erebidae_morphosp3
       Noctuidae   fuzzy/ green          Noctuidae_morphosp1
       Noctuidae   black hair/greenbody  Noctuidae_morphosp2  
       Noctuidae   fuzzy/green           Noctuidae_morphosp1 
       Saturnidae                        Polyphemous sp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `dplyr` and don't need consecutive (though unique) numbering:

```
df %>%
  group_by(lepfam) %>% 
  mutate(lep_species=ifelse(!is.na(lep_species), lep_species, 
         paste0(lepfam, "_morphosp", rank(lep_notes, ties.method ="min"))))

       lepfam            lep_notes         lep_species
        <chr>                <chr>               <chr>
1 Geometridae                 <NA>             Eois sp
2    Erebidae         black/orange  Erebidae_morphosp2
3    Erebidae         black spikes  Erebidae_morphosp1
4    Erebidae   redthorax/red legs  Erebidae_morphosp3
5   Noctuidae          fuzzy/green Noctuidae_morphosp2
6   Noctuidae black hair/greenbody Noctuidae_morphosp1
7   Noctuidae          fuzzy/green Noctuidae_morphosp2
8  Saturnidae                 <NA>      Polyphemous sp
```

Or with consecutive numbers:

```
df %>%
  group_by(lepfam) %>% 
  mutate(lep_species=ifelse(!is.na(lep_species), lep_species,
         paste0(lepfam, "_morphosp", match(lep_notes,unique(lep_notes)))))

       lepfam            lep_notes         lep_species
        <chr>                <chr>               <chr>
1 Geometridae                 <NA>             Eois sp
2    Erebidae         black/orange  Erebidae_morphosp1
3    Erebidae         black spikes  Erebidae_morphosp2
4    Erebidae   redthorax/red legs  Erebidae_morphosp3
5   Noctuidae          fuzzy/green Noctuidae_morphosp1
6   Noctuidae black hair/greenbody Noctuidae_morphosp2
7   Noctuidae          fuzzy/green Noctuidae_morphosp1
8  Saturnidae                 <NA>      Polyphemous sp
```

Comment: Hmm, this is really nice and simple code thank you. However, I am not  getting the desired output with my real data. It leaves the `lep_species` cells blank.  I understand it is hard to trouble shoot without the real data, but is there any explanation why this may not be working?

Comment: Probably because you have "" instead of NAs as missing values. Try with `mutate(lep_species=ifelse(lep_species!="", lep_species, paste0(lepfam, "_morphosp", match(lep_notes,unique(lep_notes)))))`

Comment: That in fact worked and answered my question. Thank you very much. Now, this brought a detail to my attention. If `lepfam` contains blank entries, is there a way to preform the above function ONLY on levels of lepfam that contain values. In other words, exclude `lepfam` with blanks.

Comment: try with `ifelse(lep_species!="" | lepfam=="", ...`

Comment: Your help is much appreciated! Thank you. the suggestion above worked.

Comment: Hopefully last question... I use R studio and went to view my data frame. However `View(df)` doesn't show the changes, only  the output to the code suggested above shows the changes. How do you write this to the existing dataframe or create a new dataframe with this output?

Comment: use `df <- df %>% ...` to replace original object with modified one

Comment: you may also need to clean the original data lep_notes field so it matches better: `df$lep_notes <- gsub("/ ", "/", df$lep_notes)` On your full set you may need to do more extensive cleaning

Comment: of course @HubertL. That is embarrassing...thank you