# Renames levels of factor conditional on unique levels of another factor

Tags: r

Lets say I have a dataframe like so:

```
df<- 
   plantfam        plantsp                  plantcn
   Asteraceae                               fuzzy leaf
   Asteraceae                               fuzzy leaf
   Asteraceae      Baccharis latifolia      
   Poaceae                                  3vien
   Asteraceae                               non-fuzzy leaf
```

And I want to give morpho species names to blank plantsp conditional on one factor: The plantfam should be  Asteraceae.  Thereby designating unique morpho names given the descriptors in plantcn. The output should appear as follows:

```
output<- 
   plantfam        plantsp                  plantcn
   Asteraceae      Asteraceae_morphosp1     fuzzy leaf
   Asteraceae      Asteraceae_morphosp1     fuzzy leaf
   Asteraceae      Baccharis latifolia      
   Poaceae                                  3vien
   Asteraceae     Asteraceae_morphosp2      non-fuzzy leaf
```

I have tried adapting the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44270608/8061255 and have tried the following with no success:

```
   file<-file %>%
  mutate(plantsp=ifelse(plantsp!="" | plantfam=="Asteraceae", plantsp, 
                  paste0(plantfam, "_morphosp", match(plantcn, unique 
  (plantcn)))))
```

Comment: Any chance you can help me with this version of a similar question you were able to help me with?  @HubertL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code block first, then I'll explain what I did:

```
temp <- df %>% 
        filter(is.na(plantsp)) %>% 
        group_by(plantfam, plantcn) %>% 
        summarize(plantsp=NA) %>%
        group_by(plantfam) %>%
        mutate(dummy = cumsum(!is.na(plantcn))) %>%
        mutate(plantsp = paste0(plantfam, " morpho", dummy)) %>%
        select(-dummy)
```

The first thing I suggest is to remove entries that do not require mutation `filter(is.na(plantsp))`.

Then aggregate redundant entries with `group_by(plantfam, plantcn) %>% summarize(plantsp=NA)`.

I added a `dummy` variable that counts `plantcn` in each group with `mutate(dummy = cumsum(!is.na(plantcn)))`.

I use this dummy variable for creating the string you want `mutate(plantsp = paste0(plantfam, " morpho", dummy))`.

Finally, get rid of the `dummy` column with `select(-dummy)`.

This is the resulting data frame:

```
temp
    plantfam        plantcn            plantsp
       <chr>          <chr>              <chr>
1 Asteraceae     fuzzy leaf Asteraceae morpho1
2 Asteraceae non-fuzzy leaf Asteraceae morpho2
3    Poaceae          3vien    Poaceae morpho1
```

You can add back the entries that already had `plantsp` names with:

```
new.df <- df %>% 
          filter(!is.na(plantsp)) %>%
          full_join( ., temp, by = c("plantfam","plantsp","plantcn"))
new.df
```

NOTE: You will need to do something a little more complicated if you want to keep redundant entries