# Rename levels of factor conditional on value matching within subsets of a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to assign names for blank levels of a factor `lepsp` conditional on value matching within subsets. An example of the data includes:

```
df<- 
  plantfam        lepfam         lepsp              lepcn
  Asteraceae      Geometridae    Eois sp            green/spikes
  Asteraceae      Erebidae       Anoba sp           green/nospikes                    
  Asteraceae      Erebidae                          green/nospikes            
  Melastomaceae   Noctuidae      Balsinae sp             
  Poaceae         Erebidae       Deinopa sp         black/orangespots
  Poaceae         Erebidae                          black/orangespots
  Poaceae         Erebidae       Cocytia sp         black/yellowspots
  Poaceae                                           black/yellowspots
```

Here's code for the following dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame( plantfam= c("Asteraceae","Asteraceae","Asteraceae", 
"Melastomaceae","Poaceae","Poaceae","Poaceae","Poaceae"), lepfam= 
c("Geometridae", "Erebidae","Erebidae", 
"Noctuidae","Erebidae","Erebidae","Erebidae",""), lepsp= c("Eois sp", 
"Anoba sp", "", "Balsinae sp", "Deinopa sp", "", "Cocytia sp", ""), 
lepcn= c("green/spikes","green/nospikes", "green/nospikes","", 
"black/orangespots", "black/orangespots", "black/yellowspots", 
"black/yellowspots"))
```

If a `lepsp` is blank but has a `lepcn` and that `lepcn` matches another `lepsp` that feeds on the same `plantfam`, the blank `lepsp` would be given the `lepsp` name that those conditions match. Therefore, each `lepfam` subset feeding on the same `plantfam` with the same `lepcn` will be designated the same name.

```
 output<- 
    plantfam        lepfam         lepsp              lepcn
    Asteraceae      Geometridae    Eois sp            green/spikes
    Asteraceae      Erebidae       Anoba sp           green/nospikes                    
    Asteraceae      Erebidae       Anoba sp           green/nospikes            
    Melastomaceae   Noctuidae      Balsinae sp             
    Poaceae         Erebidae       Deinopa sp       black/orangespots
    Poaceae         Erebidae       Deinopa sp       black/orangespots
    Poaceae         Erebidae       Cocytia sp       black/yellowspots
    Poaceae                        Cocytia sp       black/yellowspots
```

I have tried variations of the following without success: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479195/8061255

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataset, so that we can produce a reproducible solution?

Comment: I am under the impression the above is an example form the dataset.  What can I provide that would help further? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have added code for the example dataframe, which may be what you are requesting. Thank again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward base R with the benefit of inspecting the combinations to be renamed. In essence, you get a unique list of the plantfam/lepfam/lepcn combinations, and you merge it in with the original dataset:

Read in data and make sure formatting is as expected:

```
df<- read.csv(text = 
'plantfam,lepfam,lepsp,lepcn
Asteraceae,Geometridae,Eois sp,green/spikes
Asteraceae,Erebidae,Anoba sp,green/nospikes
Asteraceae,Erebidae,NA,green/nospikes
Melastomaceae,Noctuidae,Balsinae sp,NA
Poaceae,Erebidae,Deinopa sp,black/orangespots
Poaceae,Erebidae,NA,black/orangespots
Poaceae,Erebidae,NA,balck/yellowspots')

# assumes blanks are NA
# if blanks are actually empty strings "" then turn those into NA's

# make sure everything is a character, not a factor
df <- as.data.frame(apply(df,2,as.character),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Solution:

```
# get a unique list of all combinations that don't have missing data
dflookup <- unique(na.omit(df))

# inspect combinations to be renamed, there should be no duplicate plantfam/lepfam/lepcn combinations
dflookup

# use the lookup to merge in all known names
newdf <- merge(df,dflookup,by = c('plantfam','lepfam','lepcn'),all.x = T,suffixes = c('old','new'))

# use original lepsp when new lepsp is NA
newdf$lepsp <- ifelse(is.na(newdf$lepspnew),newdf$lepspold,newdf$lepspnew)

# remove unneeded columns
newdf$lepspold <- newdf$lepspnew <- NULL

# turn back into factors if desired
newdf <- as.data.frame(apply(newdf,2,as.factor))
```