# Renaming levels of factor conditional on unique combinations of two other factors

Tags: r

lets say I have a dataframe like so:

```
df<- 
 plantfam        lepfam                      lepsp
 Asteraceae      Geometridae                 Eois sp         
 Asteraceae      Erebidae                                     
 Poaceae         Erebidae                    
 Poaceae         Noctuidae                         
 Asteraceae      Saturnidae                  Polyphemous sp        
 Melastomaceae   Noctuidae                   
 Asteraceae             
 Melastomaceae   
                 Noctuidae
                 Erebidae
```

And I would like to make unique `lepsp` names conditional on the unique combinations of `plantfam` and `lepfam`. The output would appear as below:

```
output<- 
 plantfam        lepfam                      lepsp
 Asteraceae      Geometridae                 Eois sp         
 Asteraceae      Erebidae                    Erebidae_morphosp1                 
 Poaceae         Erebidae                    Erebidae_morphosp2
 Poaceae         Noctuidae                   Noctuidae_morphosp1      
 Asteraceae      Saturnidae                  Polyphemous sp        
 Melastomaceae   Noctuidae                   Noctuidae_morphosp2
 Asteraceae             
 Melastomaceae   
                 Noctuidae
                 Erebidae
```

Note: Each lepfam must first be subsetted. And for each unique `plantfam` `lepfam` combo within that `lepfam` subset a morpho species name is designated.For those where `plantfam` or `lepfam` are blank, a morpho species is not designated.

I have referenced the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479195/8061255
[R: For loop- For each subset, add character values that incorporate the subsetted factor level and unique iD numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44270070/8061255)

I tried  the following code without success:

```
file<-file %>%
group_by(lepfam) %>% 
mutate(lepsp=ifelse(lepsp!=""| plantfam=="" & lepfam=="", lepsp, 
                  paste0(lepfam, "_morphosp", match(lepfam, unique 
  (lepfam)))))
```

Comment: I have discovered the answer. The code should have `plantfam=="" | lepfam==""` NOT `plantfam=="" & lepfam=="" ` THUE THE CODE WILL READ:  `file<-file %>%
group_by(lepfam) %>% 
mutate(lepsp=ifelse(lepsp!=""| plantfam=="" | lepfam=="", lepsp, 
                  paste0(lepfam, "_morphosp", match(lepfam, unique 
  (lepfam)))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wanted to answer, you had already done it yourself. Anyway, I'll do it, because I am not sure your solution is correct (or maybe I misunderstood the question).

So, both of your solutions produce an output, that is different from the one given as an example.

```
df <- read.table(sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
plantfam,lepfam,lepsp\n
Asteraceae,Geometridae,Eois sp\n
Asteraceae,Erebidae,\n
Poaceae,Erebidae,\n
Poaceae,Noctuidae,\n
Asteraceae,Saturnidae,Polyphemous sp\n
Melastomaceae,Noctuidae,\n
Asteraceae,,\n
Melastomaceae,,\n
,Noctuidae,\n
,Erebidae,\n
")

df %>% group_by(lepfam) %>% mutate(lepsp=ifelse(lepsp!="" | plantfam=="" & lepfam=="", lepsp, paste0(lepfam, "_morphosp", match(lepfam, unique(lepfam)))))
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: lepfam [5]

# A tibble: 10 x 3
        plantfam      lepfam               lepsp
           <chr>       <chr>               <chr>
 1    Asteraceae Geometridae             Eois sp
 2    Asteraceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1
 3       Poaceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1
 4       Poaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1
 5    Asteraceae  Saturnidae      Polyphemous sp
 6 Melastomaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1
 7    Asteraceae                      _morphosp1
 8 Melastomaceae                      _morphosp1
 9                 Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1
10                 Erebidae   Erebidae_morphosp1

df %>% group_by(lepfam) %>% mutate(lepsp=ifelse(lepsp!="" | plantfam=="" | lepfam=="", lepsp, paste0(lepfam, "_morphosp", match(lepfam, unique (lepfam)))))
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: lepfam [5]

# A tibble: 10 x 3
        plantfam      lepfam               lepsp
           <chr>       <chr>               <chr>
 1    Asteraceae Geometridae             Eois sp
 2    Asteraceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1
 3       Poaceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1
 4       Poaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1
 5    Asteraceae  Saturnidae      Polyphemous sp
 6 Melastomaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1
 7    Asteraceae                                
 8 Melastomaceae                                
 9                 Noctuidae                    
10                  Erebidae
```

The first solution is wrong, obviously. The second one seems to be wrong too, as names are not unique: `Erebidae_morphosp1` and `Erebidae_morphosp1` are included twice.

And that is my solution. It is quite ugly and far from being elegant, but the output matches the one in the example.

```
condition <- quote(lepsp == "" & plantfam != "" & lepfam != "")
subset1 <- df %>% filter(condition) %>% group_by(lepfam) %>% mutate(lepsp = paste0(lepfam,"_morphosp",row_number()))
subset2 <- df %>% filter(condition) %>% setdiff(df, .)
union(subset1, subset2) %>% arrange(lepsp)
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: lepfam [5]

# A tibble: 10 x 3
        plantfam      lepfam               lepsp
           <chr>       <chr>               <chr>
 1                  Erebidae                    
 2    Asteraceae                                
 3 Melastomaceae                                
 4                 Noctuidae                    
 5    Asteraceae Geometridae             Eois sp
 6    Asteraceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1
 7       Poaceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp2
 8       Poaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1
 9 Melastomaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp2
10    Asteraceae  Saturnidae      Polyphemous sp
```

I shall think on it later with fresh mind, and maybe add something more elegant and shorter.

Comment: This helps but I changed the function `row_number()` to  `match(plantfam,unique(plantfam))` because in the actual dataset, not each row number was a unique/sequential `plantfam` `lepfam` interaction.  That is my error for not making  that more clear.